# Merge identical index in pandas dataseries

Tags: python, pandas

I've been struggling with this problem for a long time now, so I hope there's someone out there who can help me.

I have a timeseries in python which looks like this:

```
Dates
2011-01-10   -1500
2011-01-13    1500
2011-01-13   -4000
2011-01-26   -1000
2011-02-02    4000
2011-02-10   -4000
2011-03-03    1000
2011-03-03    2200
2011-06-03    3300
2011-05-03   -1500
2011-06-10   -1200
2011-08-01     -55
2011-08-01      55
2011-12-20    1200
dtype: int32
```

As you can see there is multiples of the same dates. I would like to merge these and then sum the values so it turns out to be:

```
Dates
2011-01-10   -1500
2011-01-13   -2500
2011-01-26   -1000
2011-02-02    4000
2011-02-10   -4000
2011-03-03    3200
2011-06-03    3300
2011-05-03   -1500
2011-06-10   -1200
2011-08-01       0
2011-12-20    1200
dtype: int32
```

Anyone who knows an solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

`ts.groupby(ts.index).sum()`

or

`ts.groupby(level=0).sum()`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your index are proper dates, you can resample to a daily interval. This intoduces NaN values at missing dates which need to be dropped afterwards:

```
ts.resample('D', how='sum').dropna()
```

A more general solution is to groupby the index, this would even work if your index would consist of strings or something else:

```
ts.groupby(lambda x: x).sum()
```

If your timestamp would also contain hourly or other information the above would not work since it groups only by equal values. You can then format the index to just the 'day part' of the timestamp with:

```
ts.groupby(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `sums = ts.groupby('Date').sum()`

You create a new series called `sums` by grouping by the Date in your `ts` time series and summing the values.